# Converting a Java String array to a php array

Tags: java, php, arrays

I have a Java string array lets say something like this:

`String [] distance = {"40","43","32","313","3123"};`

I sent this array as a POST message to the server where a php file reads this array.

`nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("distance",distance);
 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
 httpclient.execute(httppost);`

This entire array will be read in this variable: `$_POST['distance']`

I am unable to access an element in this array using `$_POST['distance[0]']`.

How can i access only one specified element from this variable

Comment: If I put your sample `String [] distance = {40,43,32,313,3123};` in a .java source file I get the error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to String` — also, Java and PHP are both generally *server-side* languages. If you're sending this array as a POST could you mean *javascript* rather than *java*?

Comment: On the other hand, `String [] distance = {40,43,32,313,3123};` isn't valid javascript syntax either.

Comment: @StephenP You are right. I have edited my java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read in the array element in PHP as:

```
$distance = explode(',', $_POST['distance']);
echo $distance[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

You have plenty of options.

1. Encode the data as JSON on the Java side and decode the string on the PHP side.
2. Post the data as a string with Java that is detected as array in PHP: `distance[]=40&distance[]=43&distance[]=32&...`
3. Work on the actual string you get and decode the native form created by Java, i.e. comma separated list of values.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but if you send string via post, you can try to replace data until you get something like this 
`40,43,32,313,3123`

and after you can use php function explode.